# download Id when sending (fetch post)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I get the id of the object I send? When I send an object, it is assigned to its id and I would like that id be saved in the PointId array
(Name, Description, X, Y) - get from the form)

```
state = {
 elements:[],
PointID:[]
}
appendElement = (Name, Description, X, Y) => {
    this.setState({
      elements: ([...this.state.elements, { Name, Description, X, Y}]),
    })
    const newItem = {
      "Name": Name,
      "Y": Y,
      "X": X,
      "RouteId": 1,
      "Description": Description
    }
    fetch("http://dearjean.ddns.net:44301/api/Points3", {
      method: "post",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(newItem)
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
      })

  };
```

Comment: How did you call appendElement?

Comment: <button onClick={() => this.appendElement(this.state.Name, this.state.Description, this.state.Y, this.state.X, this.state.RouteId)}>Add point</button>

Comment: Do you want to get the id after the async call? You can grab the id from the parameter I guess.